# Which methods can I use to calculate correlation among words in quanteda?

Tags: r, nlp, correlation, quanteda

My question is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022984/r-quantedas-textstat-simil-function).

After cleaning my text data and visualizing it using a `wordcloud`, I want to see which words are correlated to each other. Here comes the problem:

1. `quanteda`has the function `textstat_simil`, but it says
   *similarity*. So, are "similarity" and "correlation" in this case the same thing? (Is distance also related?).
2. Moreover, my *dfm* looks like a binary matrix. Is in this case phi
       correlation (from chi'squared statistics) more indicated? Can I
       calculate this via `quanteda`?
3. Do you guys have any other content rather than the source code of
           github that explain in more detail the methods to calculate
           similarity or distance measures? (I couldn't understand from
           [this](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/blob/master/R/textstat_simil.R)
           code, sorry).

Thanks for you patient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute Pearson’s product-moment correlations among features, you would use:

```
textstat_simil(x, method = “correlation”, margin = “features”)
```

The documentation makes this pretty clear, and the correlation method is the default.

Pearson’s correlation would not be the most appropriate for binary data, and we currently do not implement Spearman’s or other correlation methods more appropriate for categorical or ordinal data. However you can always coerce the dfm to an ordinary matrix (use `as.matrix()`) and then use the `stats::cor()` methods, which include Spearman’s.

As for the last question, we use the standard implementation of these measures.  If you want more clarity on what they mean, I suggest asking on Cross-Validated.

Comment: Thanks Ken! What I still didn't understand was the `Note` about this function:
"If you want to compute similarity on a "normalized" dfm object (controlling for variable document lengths, for methods such as correlation for which different document lengths matter), then wrap the input dfm in dfm_weight(x, "prop")". 
Do you any material/link which shows where does it matter?

Comment: Correlation on documents that use absolute, rather than relative frequencies, can produce results that are difficult to compare directly when the correlations involve documents of very different lengths. Better to use relative frequencies (this is the document "normalization" referred to) in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understood. If a document have 2 words, and other have 100 words, there will be a lot of words which will not appear in the first document because there is no enough words, and not because there is no "correlation" among them!! Am I right? (Weighting the matrix will overcome this problem).